# .NET Core 2.0 Vue2 TypeScript Template

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Does anyone on earth have a working version of the dotnet new vue template (https://github.com/aspnet/templating/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates) with the latest Vue 2.5.13 and Vuetify? VS2017 gives me a bunch of errors, including including Error TS2709 (TS) Cannot use namespace 'Vue' as a type. VuetifyDotnetCore2Sample-master (tsconfig project)  C:\Repos\VuetifyDotnetCore2Sample-master\node_modules\vue-router\types\router.d.ts

Found various hacks e.g. adding this in a d.ts file and referencing in tsconfig and nothing works:
import _Vue = require('vue')

declare global {
    const Vue: typeof _Vue
}

Please help, I'd really love to get going with this (new to Vue) but off to an incredibly rocky start. Here's a sample repo: https://github.com/Dev-Squared/VuetifyDotnetCore2Sample

Answer (score 0):

I saw no one posted an answer to your question. You should check out this repo as it uses the latest Vue (2.5.13) with an older version of Vuetify.

https://github.com/Dev-Squared/VuetifyDotnetCore2Sample

It's at least a starting point with something that uses Vuetify. I've been trying to do the same as you getting started with Vue and Vuetify, but it's rediculously difficult because any small thing you do will break everything.

Good luck :)